# a caveat in `Iconize`

Tags: functions, notebooks, syntax, iconize

We got this nice `Iconize` function to shrink code in notebook from version 11.3.
But, I noticed a caveat in reverting an `Iconize`-d object back:
if the wrapped stuff is comment, then the reversion (by using `Convert to Standard Form`) will give a `Null` rather than the comment before.

Say for the comment below:

```
(*some nice comment;
Plot[Sin[x],{x,-10,10}]
*)
```

If you `Iconize` it and then `Convert to Standard Form`, you'll get

```
Null
```

I think it can hardly be considered as bug as to some sense the commented code should give `Null`; but it definitely doesn't give the comment back.

So, is there any workaround to avoid `Null` if we de-`Iconize` a comment?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not a bug. `Iconize` works with expressions. Comments / line breaks / indentation and other box/input features are stripped by the FrontEnd before sending it to the Kernel.

```
Iconize[
 Hold@Range[1,
   10
   ]
 ]
(*evaluate and convert to StandardForm*)
```

> ```
> Hold[Range[1, 10]] (*no line breaks, indentation or @ *)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll use the feature with your caution/suggestion in mind.

Comment: @sunt05 how would you like to be able to use a feature like Iconize which would preserve comments etc?

Comment: the question was raised when I was planning to switch between several functions with the same name: I wrapped the alternative functions in comment so I can easily switch between them by un/commenting. As some of the alternative functions take large space, I was trying this new feature out and then fell into the `Null` scenario. Now I know I should just `Iconize` the content in the comment rather than the whole.

Comment: @sunt05 To put it more explicitly, `Iconize` preserves *expressions*, not *code*.  `f@x`, `f[x]` and `(* look: *) x // f` are different code, but represent the same expression, and therefore iconize to the same.

Comment: @Szabolcs partially better, but saying that it preserves expressions suggests it could preserve code. It is not up to `Iconize`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a follow up from Kuba's point. If you wanted to pass a few `Cell`s around (say storing a function definition) you can cache them in an `Unevaluated` manner so that they auto-write when evaluated. For instance:

```
iconizeCell[c_CellObject] :=
 With[{cont = NotebookRead[c]},
  Iconize[Unevaluated[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], cont]]]
  ]
(* insert a cell break here *)
iconizeCell@PreviousCell[]
```

[image]

and evaluating that gets me a `Cell` with:

```
iconizeCell[c_CellObject] :=
 With[{cont = NotebookRead[c]},
  Iconize[Unevaluated[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], cont]]]
  ]
```

as its content

Note that this strategy could work for function *definitions* too. e.g.:

```
iconizeDefinition[fn_] :=

 With[{defs = Association@Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[fn][[1, 2]]},
  Iconize[
   Unevaluated[
    KeyValueMap[
      Function[#[fn] = #2],
      defs
      ];
    ]
   ]
  ]

iconizeDefinition[iconizeDefinition]
```

[image]

Then running `ClearAll[iconizeDefinition]` and evaluating that blob gets me my definitions back.